# Apply Joint Effort to Gazebo Model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using Gazebo with ROS. I created a model in Gazebo that I was able to successfully send service calls to (to get a joint to spin for example). Specifically, I used the srv file gazebo_msgs/ApplyJointEffort (with a serviceClient node). What I'm trying to do now is get the nodes to be publisher/subscription-based to match another structure I am working with. Is it possible to create my own msg file based off of the gazebo_msgs/ApplyJointEffort srv in order to make a publisher node and still an effort on a joint? I tried doing just that and the publishing happens but there is no response to the model in gazebo. I'm obviously uncertain as to how the gazebo_ros package communication exactly works so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191504/apply-joint-effort-to-gazebo-model/) by [nbanyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19003/nbanyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19003/nbanyk/) on 2014-09-02**:
is this question more suited for the Gazebo forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I found out from the Gazebo board that that service call did not use physics and so was not relevant to me. Instead I was advised to use a plugin so the ROS side of things would have to involve the plugin. Closing this out.

---

Originally posted by [nbanyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19003/nbanyk/) with karma: 40 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0